Can a dryer vent duct be cleaned from the outside end?
I have stacked washer dryer installed in a closet on 1st floor & can't be moved. Can vent be cleaned from the basement and the outside vent only

We don't know since we can't see what "the basement and the outside vent" consist of.

A shop vac with a long hose (two hoses can be joined), with a small-enough diameter to fit vent, is fairly effective from outside the house. Swimming-pool corrugated plastic hoses of the right diameter also work well.
N.B.: Vacuuming alone won't do a complete job. Passing the corrugated hose through the ducts helps scrape off some of the adhered cruft, and it removes fluffy, quite flammable lint, but eventually, the duct-work and  insides of the dryer should be properly cleaned. Failure to do so is a fire hazard.

If using two hoses, join them tightly so they cannot pull apart, leaving one stuck inside the vent!
You might need to temporarily remove a flap-door on the outside vent, or to remove the vent cover, to insert the hose.
Insert the suction-side hose.
With the vacuum running, push and wiggle to get past obstructions, as far as possible.
Remove the hose and reattach the flap, if removed.

You can also use the shop vac to clean the dryer from the inside. Unplug the dryer first.

There are usually some access panels that are easily removed from the front of the dryer or from inside. Remove them to pull out a surprising amount of accumulated lint.
Using a narrow attachment, clean where the dryer's filter fits.
There are various vacuum attachments to clean by the filter, but I just use some 18 - 25 mm (3/4 - 1 inch) rubber or vinyl hose fitted to the shop vac hose with tape.

